# how to convert hexadecimal values in windows registries values to useful information

Tags: python-3.x, binary, hex, registry, information-retrieval

i have been trying to convert hexadecimal values that are present in windows registries values to whatever information they give..first i tried to print hexadecimal values as it is but what i get is...........

b'\x14\x00\x1fP\xe0O\xd0 \xea:i\x10\xa2\xd8\x08\x00+00\x9d\x14\x00.\x80\x059\x8e\x08#\x03\x02K\x98&]\x99B\x8e\x11_\xce\x002\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00com.nianticlabs.pokemongo_0.47.1-............................

how do i  get information from this

the value is present in key ....  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSavePidlMRU\apk\0

Comment: Why do you want to decode that specific key? It seems to be internal undocumented details of how Open/Save dialog works on Windows (particularly history part of it). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The thing is we are developing a forensic tool for which we have to decode that hex code to retrieve information of recently saved files....do you know how???